# Why is the copy constructor called when I am not passing an instance of the class?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I have a class Server which has a constructor:

```
Server::Server(int port) {
    // initialize some class variables
    port_ = port;
    //...
}
```

I try to create an instance of the class like so:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int port = 3000;
    Server server = Server(port);
}
```

And I get this compile error:

```
server_main.cpp:32:32: error: use of deleted function ‘Server::Server(const Server&)’
     Server server = Server(port);
                                ^
```

Now, I understand why the copy constructor was implicitly deleted, but why is it being called?

The error goes away if I add a copy constructor to the class. Is there any other way to avoid this?

Comment: Im pretty sure it is because it initialize the variable on the right side and then copy to the variable

Comment: Note that it is unlikely that it is being called (you could test your hypothesis by writing a copy constructor that prints something. That could form part of an [mcve].)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Server server = Server(port);` is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization); You're initializing `server` from a temporary `Server`.

[copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) might take place, but not guaranteed until C++17. Even copy-/move-constructor might not be called, but still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed.

You could change it to [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), which will invoke `Server::Server(int)` directly:

```
Server server(port);
```

Or [direct list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (Since C++11):

```
Server server{port};
```

**EDIT**

Since C++17, [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is guaranteed for this case.

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit
>   the copy- and move- constructors of class objects even if copy/move
>   constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects:
>
> - In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the
>     cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the
>     class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to
>     initialize the destination object:
>
>   `T x = T(T(T())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x`

So your code will work well with C++17; For copy elision being guaranteed, copy/move constructor is not required to be accessible.

[LIVE DEMO from GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5vdcGCLcYVziqXXW)

Answer (score 3):

From the very annoyingly pedantic point of view, many of the currently provided answers (if not all of them) are slightly misleading.

In C++ copy-initialization with the same type on the left-hand side and right-hand side is treated in a special way: it is immediately interpreted as an equivalent direct-initialization.

From [dcl.init]/16:

> — If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> — If the initialization is direct-initialization, **or if it is
> copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source
> type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the
> destination**, constructors are considered...

This means that your copy-initialization

```
Server server = Server(port);
```

is actually handled as direct-initialization

```
Server server(Server(port));
```

and is further processed in accordance with the rules of direct-initialization.

Rules of direct-initialization say that overload resolution is used to choose a constructor and the constructor chosen in this case is the copy-constructor (which is deleted in your case, hence the error).

So, the end result is the same - the copy constructor is required. But "branches" of the standard logic that make it required are not the ones responsible for copy-initialization, but rather the ones responsible for direct-initialization.

In this case the difference is purely conceptual. But back in the days of C++98 this obscure distinction payed important role in the functionality of [now forgotten] `std::auto_ptr` pointer (re: `auto_ptr_ref` and how it worked). This is actually often seen as an early idiomatic implementation of Move Constructor pattern (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Move_Constructor).

---

A simple example that illustrates that special handling might look as follows

```
struct A
{
    A() {}
    A(A&) {}
    A(int) {}
    operator int() const { return 42; }
};

struct B
{
    B();
    operator int() const { return 42; }
};

int main()
{
    A a1 = A(); // OK
    A a2 = B(); // Error
}
```

Note that even though both classes on the right-hand side provide a user-defined conversion to `int`, only the first initialization compiles and uses `A::A(int)` constructor. The second one fails.

The second initialization proceeds in accordance with usual copy-initialization rules. And in order to succeed it needs *two* user-defined conversions (`B -> int` and `int -> A`), which cannot be done implicitly.

The first initialization is treated in accordance with direct-initialization rules, thus effectively making the `int -> A` conversion explicit. This initialization now needs only *one* implicit user-defined conversion (`A -> int`), which is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Because you copy-initialize the `server` object.

The definition

```
Server server = Server(port);
```

is equivalent to

```
Server server(Server(port));
```

You might want to use the constructor explicitly by doing

```
Server server(port);
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic, in general `T a = x;` is equivalent to `T a(T(x));`. So `Server server = Server(port);` is actually equivalent to `Server server(Server(Server(port)))`. :) You can see why copy-elison is a thing.

Comment: @GManNickG: Unless they changed it in the recent editions of the document, copy initialization with the same type on both LHS and RHS has always been treated in a special way: `T a = x;` is immediately equivalent to `T a(x);`, with no need to involve general copy elision. A copy constructor is still required to be present.

Comment: @AnT: Ah, I didn't know that!

Comment: @GManNickG: In fact, this obscure (and most of the time inconsequential) distinction can play important role in some contexts when user-defined conversions are involved. I just wrote an answer mention this little detail.

Comment: @GManNickG That's not actually a "special case" - When you do `T a = x;`, `x` is first converted to be pass to the copy constructor, if no conversion is needed (e.g. `x` is already of type `T` or of a type derived from `T`), then this simply call `T a(x)`, otherwise this will try conversion sequence and may call `T a(T(x))` or `T a((T)x)` or something else (conversion sequences are not that easy for a comment... ).

Comment: @AnT Gcc accepts the code with [C++1z](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xKkWmBNXRq9R357x), but not with [C++14](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MDZgA0vGOfUwtqjx), is it a bug?

Comment: @songyuanyao `C++1z` introduces guaranteed copy-elision in some cases (I think this is one), which makes possible to use this kind of initialization with non-copyable/non-movable type (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html).

Comment: @Holt: OK, I misunderstood. Deleting the comment.

Comment: @Holt Seems behavior changed from C++17, copy elision is guaranteed for this case. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Copy initialization**, the `=` syntax as in `Server server = Server{port};`, requires that a copy constructor or a move constructor exists and is accessible.

Since your copy constructor doesn't exist, try to provide a move constructor.

If you can't, then your only recourse is to use **direct initialization** syntax, e.g. `Server server{port};`